# SQL Server Lock Hint inside a Transaction

Tags: sql-server

In SQL Server 2014, if I have a lock hint specified like this inside a transaction, will the table `UserTableA` be locked for the entire transaction, or only for the select query?

```
BEGIN TRAN T1

SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM UserTableA
WITH (XLOCK, ROWLOCK)
WHERE Col1 = @Value

-- Do some work

COMMIT TRAN T1
```

Comment: If you have `XLOCK` and `ROWLOCK`, it will be locked **for that single statement** only. If you want to hang on to the lock, specify `HOLDLOCK`

Comment: Even if the statement is inside a transaction correct? So in that case, it would work the same way if the SELECT statement was outside the Transaction right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> will the table UserTableA be locked for the entire transaction, or
>   only for the select query?

`X-lock` will be taken and held until the **transaction completes**.

Yuo can read it in BOL:
[Hints (Transact-SQL) - Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table)

> **XLOCK**
>
> Specifies that exclusive locks are to be taken **and held until the transaction completes.** If specified with ROWLOCK, PAGLOCK,
>   or TABLOCK, the exclusive locks apply to the appropriate level of
>   granularity.

This is because `exclusive` locks are always held until the transaction completes, and this is independent of `transaction isolation level`.

Other comment suggests to use `HOLDLOCK`, i.e. use `serializable TIL`, it could make sense when shared locks would be taken, but it's not your case, your hint means that you want `exclusive lock`.

You can easily see it in my small repro, I did 2 repro using `heap` and `clustered` table, in case of a `heap` `X-lock` on the whole table is held, in case of `clustered table` `X-lock` on the `key` and two `IX` locks on the `page` and the `key` are held:

Clustered:

[image]

Heap:

[image]